# Adding a ng-click attribute to the header value of an accordion group

Tags: angularjs, mouseevent, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to track the order in which a user clicks the headers of a bootstrap accordion. I am running into trouble trying to add a `ng-click` attribute to the repeated `accordion-group`. I am trying to limit the click area to just the header text, not the entire group. I thought a good way to do this was to pass the click `$event` into the `ng-click` function, but it is not working.

Here is a Plunker with the broken `ng-click` attribute here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yOTRVRjxRDTlnZ9Qwsk4?p=preview

Can someone kindly help me figure out the best *Angular* way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the accordion-heading for the custom header.

Here is the sample:

```
<accordion-group close-others={{oneAtATime}} ng-repeat="(key, value) in groupedByCategory" is-open="value.open" >
    <accordion-heading>
       <a ng-click="clickTrack($event)">{{key}}</a> 
    </accordion-heading>
    <div ng-repeat="c in value | orderBy: 'rating'">
      <input type="radio" name="Category" value="{{c.name}}-{{key}} "> {{c.name}} | {{c.rating}}
    </div>
  </accordion-group>
```